# PHP Create directory with permissions of another

Tags: php, file-permissions, chmod

I would like to create a directory $one with the permissions of $another:

```
mkdir($one, fileperms($another));
```

It seems to me that the above could doesn't work correctly. Please help me find the problem.

I also tried:

```
mkdir($one);
chmod($one, fileperms($another));
```

edit to clarify

```
$one = "/tmp/somedir"
$another = "/tmp/anotherdir"
```

Comment: It *seems* it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: it sets completely different permissions

Comment: Different than what? Since we don't know what is in `$one` and `$another` there is no way for us to help you here. Can you show what actually happens?

Comment: they are full paths to two arbitrary directories

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `fileperms($another)`? I'll bet it isn't what you're expecting. [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php)

Comment: what do you suggest? do you have a solution?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Plus, for argument's sake, you are closing off your `$one = "/tmp/somedir"
$another = "/tmp/anotherdir"` with `;` right? I had to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileperms($another)` is not returning what you expect it to, there is much more information than you need.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) -

> on most platforms the return value will also include information on the type of file given as filename.

To account for that you'll have to get the substring you need from `fileperms()`

```
$one = "/tmp/somedir";
$another = "/tmp/anotherdir";
mkdir($one, substr(fileperms($another), -4));
```

Comment: have you tried your code? it still doesn't work, as expected: sets a different permission from what $one has

Comment: It worked perfectly here, but I do not know what your system is returning in `fileperms()`. Can you share that @gen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and avoid using this instead of chmod

```
      $none = 'folder name';
          if (!file_exists($none)) {
              mkdir($none, 0777);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like following:

```
    $one = '/var/www/path';
    $another = 0777;
    mkdir($one);
    chmod($one, $another);
```